# Use the result of a string function in VLOOKUP to match a number

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

In cell B2 I'm pulling some characters from a cell using:

```
=MID($A2,27,2)
```

I would then like to use the result in a VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A1:D97,3,0)
```

This results in #N/A.... If I overtype the result of the formula in to cell B2 then it works correctly. What am I doing wrong?? Can string functions not be used in this way?

Comment: It seems to work, as long as the string in A2 is at least 28 characters long. Can you post any sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a number in Sheet2!A:A and hoping to return a value from column C of the same worksheet relative to the match in column A.

However, while `MID($A2,27,2)` returns text-that-looks-like-a-number, it is still returning text and you cannot lookup a number by supplying text-that-looks-like-a-number unless you are using one of the heavily-overheaded functions like [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34).

Convert the `MID($A2,27,2)` to a true number either in the B2 formula like `=--MID($A2,27,2)` or in the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) like,

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(B2), Sheet2!A$1:D$97, 3, FALSE)
```

In this formula, the [VALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VALUE-function-257D0108-07DC-437D-AE1C-BC2D3953D8C2) serves the same purpose as the [Double Unary](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/what-does-a-double-unary-operator-in-a-sumproduct/9fee1133-130f-4261-90b8-d32d5b885f9a).

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much, VALUE works! Very well explained as well, thanks for your time. I thought it may have been some sort of formatting/ "real" data issue but didn't know how to fix....

Comment: If you parse a section of text using [MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-function-230833B1-28E7-4EF8-9286-EBA06A3C29AD), [LEFT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-function-BE3191EA-D332-43E4-BAC3-810C97773A22) or [RIGHT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267EE-9AFA-4639-A02B-F19E1786CF2F) these will always be text values without some additional manipulation. The trick is to observe the default cell formatting. Numbers and dates will be right aligned by default; text will be left aligned and errors (e.g. `#DIV/0!`) are centered.

Answer (score 1):

Given the low reputation I cannot answer in the comment.

Check your data types - you might have some problems here. Generally it is certailny possible to use string functions in vlookups etc.

For example I have a number 1234 in cell A1. Then in B1 I have =MID(A1,2,2) which results in a string (not a number) 23. Then in C1 I have typed 23 which results in number 23 (not a string). Then in D1 I have =VLOOKUP(B1,C1,1,0) which results in #N/A because he finds no match against string B1 and number C1. On the other hand in E1 I have =VLOOKUP(B1*1,C1,1,0) which results in 23 because he can find a match between B1*1 (multiplication of string '23' and number 1 resulting in conversion to number 23) and a number 23.

Comment: I believe you are exactly right. Just two minutes behind me.   :P~

Answer (score 0):

If there is less than 28 characters like Tom pointed out then there is nothing for the VLOOKUP to match on.

If you use the IFERROR function you can replace the #N/A with a value of you choice.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A1:D97,3,0),"String Not Valid")
```